# Passing value from helper to class problem

Tags: apex, lightning, controller, component

Hope you can help me with my problem in regards of getting data according to category. Please see attached picture. I wanted to LOAD THE PRODUCTS according to ACCOUNT chosen on the ACCOUNT LOOK UP.

I have a custom object of PRODUCT REFERENCE with ACCOUNT ID.

Can you help me with passing the Account ID from Controller/Helper to the APEX Class. It worked but unfortunately, I need to double click the button before it work properly. :(

[image]

Here's my Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        helper.listOfAlphabet(component);
        helper.getProducts(component, event, helper);

        if (component.get('v.recordId') != null) {
            helper.getSubActivityReportDetails(component);
        }

    },

    loadCustomProducts : function(component, event, helper) {

        var data = component.get('v.defaultData');
        var term = "true";
        var results = data;
        var regex;

        var selectedProductsIDList = [];
        var selectedProductsList = [];

        //var selectedCount = component.get('v.selectedCount');

        regex = new RegExp(term, "i");
        //results = data.filter(row=>regex.test(row.isChecked));

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            selectedProductsIDList.push(
                results[i].prod2.Id
            );

            selectedProductsList.push(
                results[i]
            );

        }

        component.set('v.selectedProductsIDList', selectedProductsIDList);
        component.set('v.selectedProductsList', selectedProductsList);
        //$A.enqueueAction(component.get('c.handleClick'));

        helper.getProducts(component, event, helper);


    }
})
```

---

Helper Code:

```
getProducts : function(component, event, helper) {

        component.set("v.showSpinner", true);

        var action = component.get('c.getProducts');

        action.setParams({
            recordID : component.get('v.recordId'),
            acctID : component.get('v.selectedAccount').Id
            //acctID: component.get('v.account')
        });


        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

            var state = response.getState();

            if (state === "SUCCESS")  {

                var returnedValue = response.getReturnValue();
                var returnedValueLength = returnedValue.length;

                if (returnedValueLength > 0) {

                    this.defaultDateToday(component);

                    component.set('v.noRecordsFound', false);
                    component.set('v.defaultData', returnedValue);

                    //this.loadProducts(component);


                    var pageSize = component.get('v.pageSize');

                    component.set('v.totalRecords', returnedValueLength);
                    component.set('v.startPage', 0);
                    component.set('v.endPage', pageSize - 1);

                    var dataTableList = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < pageSize; i++) {
                        if (component.get('v.defaultData').length > i) {
                            dataTableList.push(returnedValue[i]);
                        }
                    }

                    component.set('v.dataTableList', dataTableList);                    
                    component.set('v.selectedCount', component.get('v.selectedProductsList').length);
                    component.set('v.totalPages', Math.ceil(returnedValueLength / pageSize));
                    component.set('v.showSpinner', false);
                    component.set('v.recordLoaded', false);

                }

                else {

                    component.set("v.noRecordsFound" , true);
                    component.set("v.showSpinner", false);
                    component.set('v.recordLoaded', false);

                }


            }

            else {

                var errors = response.getError();

                if (errors && Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length > 0) {

                    this.showToastDisplay({
                        "title" : "Something went wrong",
                        "message" : errors[0].message,
                        "type" : "error"
                    });

                }

            }

        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
```

---

And my Class:

//Product List

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ProductListWrapper> getProducts(String recordID, String acctID) {

        System.debug('RECORD ID: ' + recordID);

      /* Account channel = [SELECT Channel__c
                            FROM Account
                            WHERE (Id = :acctID)
                            LIMIT 1
                           ];*/

        List<Account> channel = [SELECT Channel__c
                            FROM Account
                            WHERE (ID = :acctID)
                            LIMIT 1
                           ];
        String channel2;

        if(channel.size() == 1){
            channel2 = channel[0].Channel__c;
        }
        else{
            channel2 = null;
        }

        List<CAP_Item_Ref__c> prod2List = [SELECT Id,
                                           Name
                                    FROM CAP_Item_Ref__c
                                    WHERE Channel__c = :channel2
                                    ORDER BY Name ASC
                                   ];
```

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @EranV Can you help me with passing the Account ID from Controller/Helper to the APEX Class. It worked but unfortunately, I need to double click the button before it work properly. :(

Comment: the button action started at loadCustomProducts

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if selectedAccount attribute is being updated by another component event. It is possible that it has changed to null prior to calling loadCustomProducts controller method.